# How do I 'navigate' to an activity that's already running?

Tags: android, android-activity, activation

Newbie question... So I have two activities, Cherry and Apple, and each one has a button on it to go to the other one. So back and forth.

In class "Cherry" I say this:

```
intent = new Intent(Cherry.this, Apple.class)
startActivity(intent);
```

Meaning that it should go to the Apple. There's similar code in the Apple activity.

What I think I am seeing is, is that each time when I startActivity Apple for example, it's starting a new instance of it instead of just reactivating Apple. I've scoured the doc and can't find the flag or other call that would do what I want.

Any tips would be appreciated!

-- Pito

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)?

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) is also quite useful, finishing activities on the back stack until the target activity is reached.

To be clear, your activity *may* be restarted even if using the flags above. This would happen if your activity were destroyed in an attempt to free memory. In other words, you still need to make sure your activity can handle being restarted, taking the proper precautions in `onPause` and `onSaveInstanceState`.

Answer (score 3):

Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT will bring the launched activity back to front if it's already running as given [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). You will have to handle the back button yourself so as not to finish the current activity.